# JS Cookie set in 2 places, doesn't overwrite first set

Tags: javascript, cookies, path

I am using the same script on 2 different pages, to set the same cookie. My assumption would be that even though the two pages are (slightly) different paths, they would simply overwrite the cookie instead of duplicating entries into it.

*My first page's path is:*

`example.com/classifieds/businesses`

*My second page's path is:*

`example.com/classifieds/businesses/search`

So, my question is, are cookies page-dependent; can I force them to overwrite existing values instead of writing their own page-specific values to the cookie?

*Here is what my cookie looks like with the duplicates:*

`domain=.example.com; path=/; bdView=column; bdView=detail; domain=.example.com;`

*Code for setting domain (which is in the header file)*

```
var domain = window.location.host.split(/\.(.+)/)[1];
document.cookie = "domain=." + domain;
document.cookie = "path=/";
```

*Code for setting bdView (which is in a separate js file that I include in both pages)*

```
function setCookie(view) {
    switch (view) {
        case "column":
            document.cookie = "bdView=column";
            break;
        case "list":
            document.cookie = "bdView=list";
            break;
        case "detail":
            document.cookie = "bdView=detail";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look right, you shouldn't have two `domain` fields in the cookie.

Comment: That's my problem. It duplicates instead of overwriting.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Cookies are specific to a folder, unless you use the `path` option to point them to a parent folder.

Comment: Isn't that what I did with the `path=/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I was simply using cookies wrong. I thought that domain & path were just their own things, but you're actually supposed to set them WITH the thing you're trying to set.

So, it should look like this instead:

```
function setCookie(view) {
    var domain = window.location.host.split(/\.(.+)/)[1];
    switch (view) {
        case "column":
            document.cookie = "bdView=column; path=/; domain=" + domain;
            break;
        case "list":
            document.cookie = "bdView=list; path=/; domain=" + domain;
            break;
        case "detail":
            document.cookie = "bdView=detail; path=/; domain=" + domain;
            break;
    }
}
```