# javascript COOKIE - how to add path=/?

Tags: javascript, cookies

how to add path=/ correctly?
I added a setcookie with success. But i do not get the path correctly.
If a user changes the settings (set the cookie) at a subfolder (www.domain.com/subfolder.html), it will generate a second cookie with the path /subfolder.

```
<script>

    function standardmode(){
       days=30; // number of days to keep the cookie
       myDate = new Date();
       myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
       document.cookie = 'standardmode=1; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();
    }

</script>
```

> *script from "mintedjo" Nov '08 https://www.webdeveloper.com/d/196412-creating-a-cookie-onclick-with-javascript/5*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS Cookie set in 2 places, doesn't overwrite first set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370738/js-cookie-set-in-2-places-doesnt-overwrite-first-set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.cookie = 'standardmode=1; **path=/;** expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();